# try block is working but except block is not handling error in python

Tags: python, django, try-catch, try-except

While **Handling Python dictionary key error** except block is not working but try block is working.

Below is my code

```
def catch_empty_key(a):
    try:
        return 'aaaa'
    except :
        return 'bbbb'

def zohoapicall(accesstoken): 
   accesstoken = ""
   if accesstoken == "":  
      parameters = {
            "refresh_token":"1000.06f10f49d6f00478887e3820634b928f.c045ff2a9dcb9c99057ec42645bf1e44",
            "client_id":"1000.UKZQIWVQ2A2THKSZ2126Y7E7CAA8CW",
            "client_secret":"91d25fbaeea0e81190a681708cd554a1030a9c4547",
                "redirect_uri":"https://www.google.com",
             "grant_type":"refresh_token",
        }
 
    response = requests.post("https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token?", params=parameters)
    if response.status_code == 200:
       data =   response.json()
       accesstoken = data['access_token']
     

    headers = {
   'Content-Type':'application/json',
   'Authorization':'Zoho-oauthtoken ' + str(accesstoken)
    }

    response = requests.get("https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/invoices", headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data1 = response.json()
    
        data_2=[catch_empty_key(invoice['not_a_key']) for invoice in    data1['invoices']]    
        return HttpResponse(data_2, accesstoken)
```

Here in the second last line `data_2=[catch_empty_key(invoice['not_a_key']) for invoice in data1['invoices']]`  `except` block of `catch_empty_key` function is not working and it is throwing an error.

On the Other hand if I replace second last line with something that is a `key` of `invoice` then `try` block is working and returning `aaa` as output. for example

```
data_2=[catch_empty_key(invoice['is_a_key']) for invoice in data1['invoices']]
```

I want to understand why this error is coming and how can we solve it?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It would be really great if your code had the standard indentation of 4 spaces per level. It's hard to read now.

Comment: ```KeyError at /api/user/api-call-demo``` @MaxDavies

Comment: Let me edit the code @Matthias

Comment: The `catch_empty_key` try block will not raise an error - its just returning a literal string - so the exception block will never run.

Comment: @tdelaney what can I do so that the ```except``` block will run. My Objective is to catch an error which is raised when it does not find a key in the dictionary

Comment: What do you want to happen when the key is not found in the dictionary? Return a canned value? Skip adding to the `data_2` list?

Comment: If your goal is to use `'bbbb'` as a default, you can use "get": `data_2=[invoice.get('is_a_key', 'bbbb') for invoice in data1['invoices']]`

Comment: I want to add a pre-defined value Let's say ```'NULL'```

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the concept of try-except. The code snippets need to be inside try block in order to catch any exception raised inside the snippets. In your given code, you can use it for `requests.get()` like this:

```
  headers = {
   'Content-Type':'application/json',
   'Authorization':'Zoho-oauthtoken ' + str(accesstoken)
    }
    try:
       response = requests.get("https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/invoices", headers=headers)
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)

    if response.status_code == 200:
       data1 = response.json()
    
    data_2=[catch_empty_key(invoice['not_a_key']) for invoice in data1['invoices']]    
    return HttpResponse(data_2, accesstoken)
```

Comment: How can I handle the ```KeyError at /api/user/api-call-demo``` in my second last line

Comment: Can I see what is inside the file `api-call-demo` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error gets produced when parsing the arguments you are passing, so it fails before evaluating the function; Modifying the function parameters so that the key gets checked within the function would work, for example:

```
def catch_empty_key(dict_to_check, key):
    try:
        dict_to_check[key] # error will occur if key does not exist
        return 'aaaa'
    except:
        return 'bbbb'
```

Alternatively you could check if the key exists by using `in`:

```
test = {'my':'dictionary'}
     
print('j' in test)
```

Outputs:

```
False
```

So you could simply have:

```
def catch_empty_key(dict_to_check, key):
    if key in dict_to_check:
        return 'aaaa'
    else:
        return 'bbbb'
```

Comment: How can I use this in second last line?

Comment: change it to this:
`data_2=[catch_empty_key(invoice, 'not_a_key') for invoice in data1['invoices']]`

Comment: That is, after updating the `catch_empty_key` function to one of the ones presented in the answer